# How do I put data from a while loop into a table?

Tags: python, while-loop

Basically I'm estimating pi using polygons. I have a loop which gives me a value for `n`, `ann` and `bnn` before running the loop again. here is what I have so far:

```
def printPiTable(an,bn,n,k):
"""Prints out a table for values n,2n,...,(2^k)n"""
u = (2**k)*n
power = 0
t = ((2**power)*n)
while t<=u:
    if power < 1:
        print(t,an,bn)
        power = power + 1
        t = ((2**power)*n)
    else:
        afrac = (1/2)*((1/an)+(1/bn))
        ann = 1/afrac
        bnn = sqrt(ann*bn)
        print(t,ann,bnn)
        an = ann
        bn = bnn
        power = power + 1
        t = ((2**power)*n)
return
```

This is what I get if I run it with these values:

```
>>> printPiTable(4,2*sqrt(2),4,5)

4 4 2.8284271247461903

8 3.3137084989847607 3.0614674589207187

16 3.1825978780745285 3.121445152258053

32 3.1517249074292564 3.1365484905459398

64 3.1441183852459047 3.1403311569547534

128 3.1422236299424577 3.1412772509327733
```

I want to find a way to make it instead of printing out these values, just print the values in a nice neat table, any help?

Comment: What sort of table are you looking to store it in? Image? HTML? CSV? ...picnic table?

Comment: @mhlester I want it to instead of print out those values print out a table, just a simple table. I should have probably made that clear in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use string formatting. For example,

```
        print('{:<4}{:>20f}{:>20f}'.format(t,ann,bnn))
```

produces

```
4               4.000000            2.828427
8               3.313708            3.061467
16              3.182598            3.121445
32              3.151725            3.136548
64              3.144118            3.140331
128             3.142224            3.141277
```

`{:<4}` is replaced by `t`, left-justified, formatted to a string of length 4.

`{:>20f}` is replaced by `ann`, right-justified, formatted as a float to a string of length 20.

The full story on the format string syntax is [explained here](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

---

To add column headers, just add a print statement like

```
    print('{:<4}{:>20}{:>20}'.format('t','a','b'))
```

---

For fancier ascii tables, consider using a package like [prettytable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable):

```
import prettytable

def printPiTable(an,bn,n,k):
    """Prints out a table for values n,2n,...,(2^k)n"""
    table = prettytable.PrettyTable(['t', 'a', 'b'])
    u = (2**k)*n
    power = 0
    t = ((2**power)*n)
    while t<=u:
        if power < 1:
            table.add_row((t,an,bn))
            power = power + 1
            t = ((2**power)*n)
        else:
            afrac = (1/2)*((1/an)+(1/bn))
            ann = 1/afrac
            bnn = sqrt(ann*bn)
            table.add_row((t,ann,bnn))
            an = ann
            bn = bnn
            power = power + 1
            t = ((2**power)*n)
    print(table)


printPiTable(4,2*sqrt(2),4,5)
```

yields

```
+-----+---------------+---------------+
|  t  |       a       |       b       |
+-----+---------------+---------------+
|  4  |       4       | 2.82842712475 |
|  8  | 3.31370849898 | 3.06146745892 |
|  16 | 3.18259787807 | 3.12144515226 |
|  32 | 3.15172490743 | 3.13654849055 |
|  64 | 3.14411838525 | 3.14033115695 |
| 128 | 3.14222362994 | 3.14127725093 |
+-----+---------------+---------------+
```

---

Perhaps it is overkill for this sole purpose, but [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) can make nice tables too, and can export them in other formats, such as HTML.

Comment: If you want to have a more permanent solution, you can use this answer to save to a file also. I won't add a new answer but it would be a good addition to this answer.

Comment: Is there any way to add column headers

Answer (score 0):

You can use output formatting to make it look pretty.  Look here for an example:
http://docs.python.org/release/1.4/tut/node45.html